# SQL: Split a row into multiple rows based on certain rules

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is my table in my Microsoft Access database:

```
Terr(Prim)    Terr(Sec)   Qty
----------    ---------   -------  
A             A           0.5   
A             B           0.5
```

I want to change it to like this through SQL:

```
Type           Terr   Qty
-----------    ----   ----  
Original       A      0.5   
Original       A      0.5
50-50 give     A      -0.5
50-50 take     B      0.5
```

Rules:

1. Create two columns, [Type] and [Terr]
2. if [Terr(Prim)] = [Terr (Sec)], then keep the row and [Type] = "Original"
3. if [Terr (Prim)] <> [Terr (Sec)], then:

   - Row 1: [Type] = "Original", [Terr] = [Terr(Prim)], the other columns remain the same
   - Row 2: [Type] = "50-50 Give", [Terr] = [Terr (Prim)], [Qty] turns into negative
   - Row 3: [Type] = "50-50 take", [Terr] = [Terr (Sec)], the other columns remain the same
4. delete [Terr(Prim)] and [Terr (Sec)]

Comment: Where [Terr (Prim)] <> [Terr (Sec)],, you can do the three inserts with an insert statement (append query) followed by a three select statements with UNION statement after the first and second select (or possibly a self-join with the same table three times), but if you're using MS-Access SQL, you can't do an insert (append) statement and delete together in the same query (not an insert and update), which makes it tricky.  So, I think this will be quicker in VBA.  Are you asking for help writing the VBA code for this? Also, please confirm you're using MS-Access SQL.

Comment: I am working on Microsoft Access. The issue has been soloved by ShA.t. Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT "Original" As [Type], [TerrPrim] AS [Terr], Qty
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT "50-50 Give" As [Type], [TerrPrim] AS [Terr], -Qty
FROM t
WHERE [TerrPrim] <> [TerrSec]
UNION ALL
SELECT "50-50 take" As [Type], [TerrSec] AS Terr, Qty
FROM t
WHERE [TerrPrim] <> [TerrSec];
```